# How to compare two arrays in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having two arrays, how can i compare the two arrays at single shot.

```
   var arr1= ["a","b","c"];
   var arr2 = ["a","c","d"]

   if(arr1 == arr2){
      console.log(true);
    }else{
      console.log(false);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
var arr1 = ["a","b","c"];
var arr2 = ["a","c","d"];

if (arr1.length == arr2.length
    && arr1.every(function(u, i) {
        return u === arr2[i];
    })
) {
   console.log(true);
} else {
   console.log(false);
}
```

---

Side note for edge cases:

`===` is often considered slightly broken for this kind of task because `NaN` behaves unexpectedly:

```
var arr1 = ["a",NaN,"b"];
var arr2 = ["a",NaN,"b"];

if (arr1.length == arr2.length
    && arr1.every(function(u, i) {
        return u === arr2[i];
    })
) {
   console.log(true);
} else {
   console.log(false);
}
```

The code above actually logs `false` because `NaN !== NaN`. In addition, `===` can't distinguish `+0` from `-0`.  To cover both of these cases, you could use a stronger comparison known as "egal" or "is", which can easily be implemented like so:

```
function is(a, b) {
    return a === b && (a !== 0 || 1 / a === 1 / b) // false for +0 vs -0
        || a !== a && b !== b; // true for NaN vs NaN
}

var arr1 = ["a",NaN,"b"];
var arr2 = ["a",NaN,"b"];

if (arr1.length == arr2.length
    && arr1.every(function(u, i) {
        // Use "is" instead of "==="
        return is(u, arr2[i]);
    })
) {
   console.log(true);
} else {
   console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Note that this might give the wrong results in case arr1 is shorter then arr2 - try:
`var arr1 = [ 'a', 'b' ], arr2 = ['a','b','c'];`

Include a simple length comparison before the every, and you're done:
`if( arr1.length === arr2.length && arr1.every( ...`

Comment: Very good point, Erwin. I have updated my answer to include the length test you have suggested. Thanks!

Comment: if the value exists but in different position then will this algorithm still works?

Comment: This assumes the two arrays are sorted the same way.

Answer (score 8):

[ES6]

Top answer is good & enough.

But when you just want to compare its values are same you have to sort it before.
here's no need sort code.

```
if(arr1.length == arr2.length && arr1.every((v) => arr2.indexOf(v) >= 0)) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

And.. I think using a 'some' instead of 'every' is better.

If those are not same, 'some' gives you a early exit. - very little early but early ;)

```
if(arr1.length == arr2.length && !arr1.some((v) => arr2.indexOf(v) < 0)) {
    console.log(true);
} else {
    console.log(false);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would make use of [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#difference) for this.

```
var same = (_.difference(arr1, arr2).length == 0)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. 
`_ = require('underscore'); _.difference(["a","c"], ["a","c","d"]).length;`
returns:
`0`

Same for `lodash`.

Answer (score 3):

The top answer is good, but I would also consider using Array.prototype:

```
Array.prototype.equals = function (arr) {
    return this.length == arr.length && this.every((u, i) => u === arr[i]);
}

console.log([1,2,3].equals([1,2,3])); // true
console.log([1,2,3].equals([1,3,3])); // false
// BUT!
console.log(["a",NaN,"b"].equals(["a",NaN,"b"])); // false, because NaN !== NaN
```

If you want it to work for NaNs too and distinguish +0 and -0, better use this:

```
Array.prototype.equals = function (arr) {
    function is(a, b) { // taken from the top answer
        return a === b && (a !== 0 || 1 / a === 1 / b) // false for +0 vs -0
            || a !== a && b !== b; // true for NaN vs NaN
    }
    return this.length == arr.length && this.every((u, i) => is(u, arr[i]));
}

console.log(["a",NaN,"b"].equals(["a",NaN,"b"])); // true
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another one, without ES5 `every`:

```
function arrEq(arr1, arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++)
    if (arr1[i] != arr2[i])
      return false;
  return i == arr2.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add some modification of the code made by 'Taihwan Hah' but could not leave a comment (the system told me so)

So here is my modifs:

```
function ArrayEquals(arr1,arr2){
    return arr1.length === arr2.length && !arr1.some((v) => arr2.indexOf(v) < 0) && !arr2.some((v) => arr1.indexOf(v) < 0);
}
```

basically, I had to check for but array because my arrays do not contains unique numbers.

Answer (score 1):

(Although the question is much older than v9.0.0, but) since the question is about Node - starting from Node v9.0.0 you can use the built-in "util" module's [isDeepStrictEqual(arr1, arr2)](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_isdeepstrictequal_val1_val2) for comparing arrays (or objects, or anything for that matter)

```
const util = require('util');
let arr1 = [1,2,3];
let arr2 = [1,2,3];
let arr3 = [1,3,2];
console.log(util.isDeepStrictEqual(arr1, arr2)) // true
console.log(util.isDeepStrictEqual(arr1, arr3)) // false
```

Also works for NaN

There is also a non-strict version of this: https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assertdeepequalactual-expected-message

Answer (score 0):

I would like to improve the answer from staackuser2 a little bit:

```
var same = (arr1.length === arr2.length) && (_.difference(arr1, arr2).length === 0)
```

or

```
var same = (_.difference(arr1, arr2).length === 0) && (_.difference(arr2, arr1).length === 0)
```