# How do I compare two arrays in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have two arrays

```
["a", "b", "c"]

["c", "a", "b"]
```

What is the best way to compare these two arrays and see if they are equal (they should come as equal for the above scenario)

Comment: possible duplicat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523611/how-to-compare-two-arrays-in-node-js

Comment: Clearly a duplicate; the only missing link is pre-sorting both compared arrays first.

Comment: @pronox That solution doesn't work

> var arr1 = ["a","b","c"];
undefined
> var arr2 = ["c","a","b"];
undefined
> if (arr1.length == arr2.length
...     && arr1.every(function(u, i) {
.....         return u === arr2[i];
.....     })
... ) {
...    console.log(true);
... } else {
...    console.log(false);
... }

false

Comment: then how is it marked accepted and up voted few times, let me check i

Comment: @bluesman its working

Comment: @pronox There was a missing step to sort the array as thefourtheye showed in his solution

Answer (score 4):

```
function compareArrays(array1, array2) {
    array1 = array1.slice();
    array2 = array2.slice();
    if (array1.length === array2.length) {       // Check if the lengths are same
        array1.sort();
        array2.sort();                           // Sort both the arrays
        return array1.every(function(item, index) {
            return item === array2[index];       // Check elements at every index
        });                                      // are the same
    }
    return false;
}

console.assert(compareArrays(["a", "b", "c"], ["c", "a", "b"]) === true);
```

Comment: You are changing the arrays as a side effect

Comment: @Esailija Fixed it :) Please check now.

Comment: Sure but why not `return array1.length === array2.length && array1.every(item => array2.indexOf(item) > -1);` much simpler and faster :P

Comment: @Esailija I test the solutions before I post them. That is ES6 and I couldn't test that :(

Comment: @Esailija Apart from that, technically that is O(N^2), I believe

Comment: Yes but that doesn't mean anything in terms of real performance. I also use arrow function syntax because it's easier to read in a comment.

Comment: @Esailija Oh, got it :) But, if there are duplicate elements in one list and the second list doesn't, this will fail, right? For example, `["a", "a"]` and `["a", "b"]`?

Comment: The OP is representing sets as arrays so uniqueness is assumed yes

Comment: @Esailija If the data is guaranteed to be unique, converting the arrays to Objects will be better, right? We get faster lookup. for larger arrays?

Comment: @thefourtheye That only works if the items are all strings.  I see no reason to believe that is the case.

Comment: @AaronDufour You are correct, I don't claim that it will work always :) Also OP says `they should come as equal for the above scenario`. This solution was mainly targeted at that statement.

Comment: The question here is what does it mean to have two arrays that are equal? Does it mean that the arrays have the same elements, or does it mean that the arrays indices match?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with  [`_.difference`](http://underscorejs.org/#difference)

```
var diff = _(array1).difference(array2);
if(diff.length > 0) {
    // There is a difference
}
```

this will not work because different returns diff from first array.
_.difference(['a'] ,['a','b']) is 0 but two array is not equal.